can my code have possibly invalid memory access while creating QueryContext in Go?
I wrote the code as below.
rows, err := s.db.QueryContext(context.TODO(), "select * from mytable")
if err != nil {
        log.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "query": queryString,
        }).Errorln("failed to query, ", err)
        return err
    }
resultString, err := getResultString(rows)

Also I added the getResultString as below.
func getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) (*string, error) {
    defer rows.Close()

    var result string
    if rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&result); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("scan err, %v", err)
        } else {
            return &result, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("query err, %v", rows.Err())
}

This code is wrote based on the example of how to use the query in the gosnowflake.
While running the app, sometimes the memory issues occurred as below.
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0x7d8848]
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   goroutine 143 [running]:
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake.(*snowflakeRows).Close(0x10?)
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   /home/ec2-user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake@v1.6.23/rows.go:67 +0x18
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   database/sql.(*Rows).close.func1()
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   /usr/lib/golang/src/database/sql/sql.go:3287 +0x34
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   database/sql.withLock({0xb788d8, 0x40033dbc20}, 0x40008ecf48)
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   /usr/lib/golang/src/database/sql/sql.go:3405 +0x7c
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   database/sql.(*Rows).close(0x4000097980, {0x0, 0x0})
2024-05-14T13:42:08.689+09:00   /usr/lib/golang/src/database/sql/sql.go:3286 +0x130

After struggling to fix this issue, but I suspect the one point.
As you can see above, I created the rows in the function and passed them to another function (getResultString) as an argument. While this procedure, I think that some memory corruption might occur because the code examples that I have seen is all the logics is included in the one function, which is contrast to my code.
So I suspect that the passing the row to other function can lead to potential problem.
Is my suspect reasonable? Otherwise, do you have any suggestion for resolving the issue?
Thanks,

// Close closes the [Rows], preventing further enumeration. If [Rows.Next] is called
// and returns false and there are no further result sets,
// the [Rows] are closed automatically and it will suffice to check the
// result of [Rows.Err]. Close is idempotent and does not affect the result of [Rows.Err].

actually Close() does nothing here, See this link
https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/blob/c355711dbd1f9ab10dfbfdcdd194656c23abb45d/rows.go#L76
and there is no issue with your code, it's mostly a bug from the github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake library.
also please keep refactoring the getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) as below:
func getResultString(rows *sql.Rows) (*string, error) {
    if err = rows.Next(); err != nil {
        // Next failed with an error, you can wrap the error using errors.Join
        return nil,err
    }
    var result string
    if err = rows.Scan(&result); err != nil {
        // scan fails
        return nil,err
    }
    return &result,nil
}

